# Show node form on preview page

Tags: 8, nodes

Is it possible to show node edit form on preview page without need to click on "back to content editing"? If yes, how?

**Why?**

1. I'm migrating a website from older Drupal version and "my" users are used to original behaviour. The target audience is not very experienced with computers, so any changes to them are scary and unwelcomed.
2. It's extra click-and-wait and even I found it bit annoying during development; I couldn't get used to it during 3/4 of year I'm working on the migration.

Note:  I found that `NodePreviewController` class is responsible for the preview page and that `NodeForm` class is responsible for the edit form, but I'm missing knowledge of whole picture, i.e. how to connect these two together in Drupal-way without breaking anything and how to connect the form to previously submitted data.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you know about the Twig Tweak module and their `{{ drupal_entity_form('node', 123) }}` function? Or maybe a custom block holding that form being visible only on the preview route, getting the node from context?

Comment: @leymannx "What do you have so far?" If you mean practically, nothing except knowledge that after a few hours of Googling, I surprisingly found absolutely nothing. If you mean theoretically, I found that `NodePreviewController` class is responsible for the preview page and that `NodeForm` class is responsible for the edit form, but I'm missing knowledge of whole picture, i.e. how to connect these two together in Drupal-way without breaking anything and how to connect the form to previously submitted data. And no, I didn't know about that module, I'll check it out.

Comment: Ah uh, I just tried it out with `{{ drupal_entity_form('node', 123) }}` and the problem is that there is no node ID yet if the form hasn't been saved at least once. You say in Drupal 7(?) you had the form on the preview page, was that default back then? Or was there another module involved to provide this feature?

Comment: @leymannx You're fast, I didn't got to try that yet. Actually, it's Drupal 6. And yes, it was default behaviour - when you clicked on Preview button, it showed Teaser preview, under that was Full preview and under that was form which allowed directly continue editing/creating the node. So user didn't need to do any other steps and wait to continue writing.

Comment: (Btw. I know I should upgrade from D6 long time ago. When I created the web ~10 years ago, I was student and had lots of time during summer holidays. However, when time of D6 was close to it's end, I simply didn't have time in my life until last year...)